# Grails maxSize constraint not making texbox bigger

Tags: grails

I am currently learning Grails (version 3.2.5) from [this video series](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PXHxo43hn34).
I'm following the instructions, and when I change the `maxSize` of the box to make it bigger it fails to do so. Is there something wrong on the code? I can’t seem to find the problem.

```
class Task {
    String summary
    String details
    Date dateCreated
    Date deadline
    Long timeSpent = 0L
    static  hasMany = [tags: Tag]


    static constraints = {
        summary blank: false, unique: true
        details blank: false, maxSize: 1000
        deadline nullable: true
        timeSpent min: 0L
    }
    String toString() {return summary}
}
```

Bonus question: if I run the program with `details blank:false` and then remove the line of code and reload the program it still acts like the code is there (still asks for the box to be filled). Only when I go and put back `details blank: true` does the restriction go off.

Comment: You might want to include what version of Grails you are using in your question. That's going to be helpful in answering your question.

Comment: @JoshuaMoore thanks i just updated it.

Comment: constraints should be pre-configured thought of - meaning once a table is created with specific constraints updates usually will not work. When it automatically creates the tables through the update scheme it sets the constraints up so hence blank false true will apply / work fine with an internal db. You may find you need to restart the app for your changes to work properly. With physical db such as mysql you would have to manually update those constraints once created

Comment: @vahid Actualy i did restart the app and the restriction was still applied even if i had no code.

Comment: `blank:false` vs `nullable:false`. You need to set them both to be true in your case so `details blank: true, nullable:true, maxSize: 1000` . Blank simply suggests the form field exists or is posted back but can be a blank entry where as nullable means the field does not have to be provided at all and does not have to exist on the form page.

Comment: @TeraBlitz I recall that during the updates of grails I think from 2.3 http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/Grails-2-3-Data-Binding-String-Trimming-And-Null-Conversions-td4645255.html

Comment: @vahid thanks for all this information its very useful for me

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a textarea instead of a textfield, you should add the widget property in the constraint, so it should be like this:

```
details blank: false, maxSize: 1000, widget:'textarea'
```

Check the documentation at http://docs.grails.org/3.2.5/ref/Constraints/widget.html